# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'?

Tags: python, firebase, fastapi

```
@app.post("/create-user/{user_id}")
def create_user(user_id : int, user : User ):
    ref = db.reference('/' )
    
    ref.update({
        
        users:{


            "name": user.name,
            "id": user.id,
            "activation_key" : user.activation_key ,
            "creation_date": user.creation_date , 
            "customer_email":user.customer_email,
            "password": user.password
        
        }
 
    })

    if user_id in users:
        return{"Error" : "User already exists"}

    users[user_id] = user

    return users[user_id]
```

Can please someone help me to reslove it? from ref.update({  I am getting this error

Comment: You have a typo.  In the 5th line, you have `users:{` where you meant to have `"users":{`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want use `user` instead of `users` inside dictionary

The error may be occurring because the variable `user` is of type `User`
and dictionary can't hold that type of object.

Try replacing `users` with `"users"` or you may use any other logic to store all details within `user` in a tuple and use it as a key.